# Limit rows of each `intime` field to 30

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using following select statement to generate random data for one year

```
 SELECT a intime
    ,a + format('%s', b || ' minutes')::interval otime
    ,b duration
FROM generate_series('2016-01-01 07:00:00'::timestamp, '2016-12-31 16:00:00', '05 minutes') s(a)
    ,generate_series(5, 20, 5) t(b)
where a::time between '07:00:00'
        and '16:00:00';
```

This will produce 436 rows for each day in a month but how can I limit it to 30 rows in each day from `2016-01-01` to `2016-12-31`

Comment: What does "random" have to do with your query?  The values look  precisely generated to me.  Please show examples of what you are trying to generate.

Comment: Any 30 number of rows in a day, I want to limit the number rows to 30 or a specific value instead of the default number of rows in a day

Comment: @gabriele based on the StartTime and EndTime as well as the interval?

Comment: @LONG no need to match the time, Looking to limit the existing result to 30 rows for each date, for example the given query produce 436 rows for date `2016-01-01` and ``2016-01-02` (for each days) here i just want to limit or show 30 rows for each dates

Answer (score 0):

If you want 30 equal spaced times during a day:

```
SELECT s.a
FROM generate_series('2016-01-01'::timestamp, '2016-12-31',
                     '48 minutes') s(a)
```

Comment: I have this condition `time between '07:00:00'
        and '16:00:00'`